Trading pair of cointegrated stocks using options
Suppose stock A and B are cointegrated and a trading signal is dervied from it. Instead of long the underperforming and short the over-performing stock, what about long at the money call and put options for the underperforming and overperforming stock respectively,  at quantities equivalent to the hedge ratio from the cointegration model?
Let's assume the current IV of both options are low and there are no upcoming earnings call/major announcements within the next 2* half lives of the spread. Are there other risks to be aware of?

How's your vol forecast? Time to convergence forecast? + transaction costs and liquidity considerations.
Unless the above are nailed and have demonstrable edge then I'd argue you're adding complexity needlessly.

I think this is key. If you just want exposure to the stock(s) movements, options are probably not the right tool for the job.

Right, I was coming from the angle of adding leverage to the returns. But seems like it creates more risk for slippage
